# OnContextItemSelected async call

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin, task

**Problem**

I override the method bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item) in Xamarin Android to catch when the user clicks on a context menu.

When the user click on a specific item in the menu, I call a webservice to remove some information related to the row clicked.

I want to remove the information without blocking the UI thread, but still have control of the execution. Do you have any ideas? Any Task black magic? :-)

**Constraints**

1) I cannot use the async keyword in OnContextItemSelected because it would change the return type from bool to Task

2) The webservice call should not block the UI thread.

**Attemped solutions**

1) Changing the return type to Task and somehow still override the method.

2) Using Task task = Task.Run(async () => ....) and then Task.Wait()

3) Using Task task = Task.Run(async () => ... ) without wait. I works but I have no control of when the task is completed.

**Example code**

```
public override bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
            if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.delete)
            {
                   ...
                   //Call webservice without blocking the UI thread
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you implement another `async` method that you call from your event handler:

```
private async Task TellWebServiceToRemoveAsync()
{
    await webService.RemoveAsync(); // or whatever it's called
    // do what you need to do when webservice has finished
    // this will happen on the UI thread again
}

public override bool OnContextItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.delete)
    {
        TellWebServiceToRemoveAsync();
        return true;                   
    }
}
```

The compiler turns `TellWebServiceToRemoveAsync()` into a *state machine*. At the `await` keyword the control flow is returned to the caller (your event handler and from there to the UI).

When the asynchronous webservice call is completed, the execution of `TellWebServiceToRemoveAsync()` is resumed *after* the `await` keyword, but *on the UI thread*.

So you can manipulate your UI controls from there.

Comment: How would I manipulate the UI controls after TellWebServiceToRemoveAsync is completed? How do I know when it's completed?

Comment: @MortenGR you can manipulate your controls _inside_ `TellWebServiceToRemoveAsync`. Execution is resumed after the `await` when the webservice call is completed. Updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent. Seems to be working as intended. Is it correct that I can use Task task = TellWebServiceToRemoveAsync();to avoid the compiler warning: Because the call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before...

Comment: @MortenGR yes that's correct. Indeed it's what the compiler warning suggests to do.